# How to automate currency rates in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.0

Hey guys I'm having problem in magento 2 currency rate. I have a question is it also possible to automate magento 2 currency for example euro, gbp and usd? can you show me the process on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If server's cron is running and if you are able to get currency rates in **Store >> Currency >> Currency Rates** by clicking on **Import button**, then you can automate the process of updating currency rates.

To do so:

- Go to **Stores** >> **Configuration** >> **Currency Setup** (under **General** tab).
- Under **Scheduled Import Settings**, set **Enabled** to **Yes**, select **Service** and set other required settings.
- Click on **Save Config** button.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Hey bro thanks for the response. I will let you know if I have problems along the way in magento 2. thank you-

Comment: I am finding that even though the cron task runs on Ubuntu the currencies are not updated. I've tried with both Yahoo and Fixer.io. If I try manually with /usr/bin/php /home/example/public_html/bin/magento cron:run I get no error, just the message "Ran jobs by schedule", yet no currencies are updated. Magento CE 2.1.7.

If I click the import button in the back end for either service they are updated, but I'd rather not have to do this manually every day.

Comment: You can debug the problem by enabling logs. Enable logs from the admin panel, Delete logs in /var/log folder and check log folder after cron has been run once.

Comment: i have import currency rate using fixer.io, all latest rate save and i have set cron job after every 1 minutes for currency rate update and set my email, my question is when i am get email, see my setting . https://www.screencast.com/t/5TRJvmCRrxPN

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I can't update currency rate by magento cron anymore. So I created this extension https://github.com/thanhdv2811/Magento-2-Currency-Convert to update currency rate using other services.